# Refresh camera stream jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, refresh, webcam

i'm using `getUserMedia` to display the webcam stream in a div. 
I'm trying to apply some CSS effects to the video stream, like `filter : blur(15px);` and some other CSS effects.

The problem is that the effect doesn't work, when i'm applying the class, but it works if it's loaded like if it's on `.effect0` at the loading of the page.

Does anybody know how i can refresh only the camera stream to see the effect, and can explain to me how to include it in my code ?

Thanks a lot if you read me and thanks again if you help !

My code :

```js
      var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia || navigator.oGetUserMedia;
    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.getUserMedia({
            video: true
        }, handleVideo, videoError);
    }

    function handleVideo(stream) {
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    }

    function videoError(e) {
        // do something
    }

    $('.bouton0').click(function () {
        $('#videoElement').removeClass('.effet1');
        $('#videoElement').addClass('.effet0');
    });
    $('.bouton1').click(function () {
        $('#videoElement').removeClass('.effet0');
        $('#videoElement').addClass('.effet1');
    });
```

```css
#container {
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-top: 10%;
}
#videoElement {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #666;
}

.effet0 {
    filter: none;
}
.effet1 {
    filter: blur(15px);
}

ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="bouton0">effet 0</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="bouton1">effet 1</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="container">
        <video autoplay="true" id="videoElement" class=""> </video>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be
`$().removeClass('.effet1'); -> $().removeClass('effet1');`

Other also. :)